# Mp4 with baseline profile and h264 encoding is not playable in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, gstreamer, nvidia, h.264

Chrome mp4 with baseline profile is not playable in chrome using html5 video tag

**I have 2 videos 1 is playable in chrome and one is not.**

About Video playable in chrome
1 downloaded from youtube 2changed profile to baseline using ffmpeg 3then put the video under html video tag and its playable

**info of the video using ffmpeg :
Video 1 which is playable on chrome
$ ffmpeg -i BaselinePlayable.mp4**

[Mp4PlayableInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdlG6.png)

About Video not playable in chrome
  1 This video is generated using gstreamer having nvidia graphic card from an 
  incoming stream.
  2 it was generated as baseline profile
  3 then put the video under html video tag and its not playable

**info of the video using ffmpeg :
Video 2 which is not playable on chrome
$ ffmpeg -i BaselineNotPlayable.mp4**
[Mp4NotPlayableInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUM4o.png)

Sample code of python for video not playable
[code for video not playable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjL8x.png)

video streaming codec information to be playable on chrome:
[codec info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lYxf.png)

Sample html code which i have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>
Testing H264 on chrome html5
</h1>
<video width="800" controls>
  <source src="tcp://[2612:f777:f:240e::898]:55151" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</body> 
</html>
```

i have tried above code with by replacing tcp with http

Comment: You don't specify how you created the not working file. judging by the output of FFmpeg, this is not an MP4 file.

Comment: I am using gstreamer and nvidia graphic card for fetch the streaming from Set top box.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch  Just wanted to  know how did you conclude that this is not an mp4.  Also i have added video not playable code in my question

Comment: The one that plays shows correctly `Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2` while the one that does not play shows `Input #0, mpeg`. I assume you have created an MPEG TS stream instead of an MP4 file. Also I cannot see any muxer in your file creation pipeline.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Thanks for the input.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch thanks for the input.. i have changed the multiplexer and changed it to mp4.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Now i am working with the live streaming. whose media information is updated in question as screenshot. I have created small html file and passed both http and tcp url in video tag of html5 but its not playing on chrome . i